# Want Logitech multi-button wireless non-Bluetooth mouse with non-Unifying receiver

Tags: wireless, mice, logitech

I have a Logitech set: mouse (M185) + keyboard (K270). It uses a pre-Unifying receiver (this is how I understand it), one for both mouse and keyboard. I would like to replace the mouse with some other (with more than 3 buttons) but I would like to leave the same receiver.

Which Logitech mice are:

- wireless
- use a non-Unifying receiver
- not Bluetooth, and
- have more than 3 buttons?

How can I find them? I didn't find a way to filter by the type of receiver…

I also did tests with a Unifying mouse and the Unifying Software does not see my keyboard while the Logitech Connection Utility (this is how the software for pairing these non-Unifying devices is called) does not see the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

A manual search was required to find:

[G305](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gaming-mice/g305-lightspeed-wireless-gaming-mouse.910-005280.html#product-tech-specs)
[G502](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gaming-mice/g502-lightspeed-wireless-gaming-mouse.910-005565.html#product-tech-specs)
[G604](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gaming-mice/g604-lightspeed-wireless-gaming-mouse.910-005622.html#product-tech-specs)
[G703](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gaming-mice/g703-hero-wireless-gaming-mouse.910-005638.html#product-tech-specs)
[G903](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gaming-mice/g903-hero-wireless-gaming-mouse.910-005670.html#product-tech-specs)
[Pro Gaming](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gaming-mice/pro-wireless-mouse.910-005270.html#product-tech-specs)

Comment: This is technically correct answer however it does not solve my problem. I bought G305 and it does not work with my receiver, I doubt any Logitech G mice will. My only hope is in old (no longer officially sold) devices but I have no way of finding them…